# Django - how to add email to required things

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I create registration form:

```
#urls.py
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from account.views import Register

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^register/$', Register.as_view(template_name='account/register.html')),
)

#views.py
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Register(CreateView):
    model = User
    success_url = '/account/'
```

And i have question: how I can add that email be require (now I must only enter username, password and 2 times time).

@edit
And how "repair" password? When i create user (in this form) and then go to admin panel, in user i see "Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm.". How i can repair this?

Comment: I would suggest you to use already built authentication and registration apps e.g. [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth), [userena](https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena), [django-registration](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration).

Comment: These packages handles lots of stuff for you. And they can be easily br customize according to need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that email is not required is because you're using a `ModelForm`, which takes a lot of cues from the underlying `User` model. Specifically, the `required=True` attribute is not present on the `email` field of the model.

One solution is to create your own form with the necessary attributes, perhaps by using a ModelForm and adding a required email field.

Another solution, and probably the better one, is to use something like [django-registration](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration) as mentioned by Aamir Adnan in the comments to your question. It'll simplify things a lot for you.

As far as your `repair password` goes, you can't set the password to a raw string value as you're doing with your `CreateView`. To set a password, you have to call `user.set_password(raw_string)` which will take care of hashing and salting for you. Look how the built in [UserCreationForm](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L61) works, and try to mimic it if you decide to build the form yourself, rather than using a library (you shouldn't).

Answer (score 0):

To solve these two problems you can use form like:

```
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):    
    class Meta:
        model = User

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserCreationForm).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['email'].required = True

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

class Register(CreateView):
    model = User
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = '/account/'
```

But there'll be other problems like duplication of username.